# Not able to upgrade my galaxy ace through kies

Tags: samsung-kies, samsung-galaxy-ace

When i connect my ace through kies the update starts, it downloads the firmware from the internet and then it shows "preparing firmware upgrade components" and it stuck their as it is, nothing changed and it was taking a hell lot of time....I left it in the same condition over nite but still no changes.....help me.

Comment: There are a number of questions here tagged [tag:samsung-kies] that describe similar issues but with different phones. Have you checked to see if any of those solutions help you?

Answer (score 0):

Just reboot the phone, restart Kies and try again.